# How to convert QPointf to QPoint in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to know how can i convert a QPointf position into a QPoint position in PyQt, because i need to set the mouse position using the position of an item.
I've been trying with this, but nothing happens:

```
xq=node.pos().x()
yq= node.pos().y()
x=int(xq)
y=int(yq)
QtGui.QCursor.setPos(x,y)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try these commands in the interpreter:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
point = QtCore.QPointF(100.2, 144.23)
QtGui.QCursor.pos(), QtGui.QCursor.setPos(point.toPoint()), QtGui.QCursor.pos()
# (PyQt4.QtCore.QPoint(1335, 691), None, PyQt4.QtCore.QPoint(100, 144))
```

But the real problem is probably that you use item coordinates, which you have to map to global coordinates.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15808971/521590). Basically he maps coordinates in the following way:

> item -> scene -> view -> global

Answer (score -1):

Answer to the question in the title:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpointf.html#toPoint

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore
pointf = QtCore.QPointF(100.2, 144.23)
point = pointf.toPoint()
print(point) # PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(100, 144)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34596694)